# Discord.js Reaction printing format issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am coding reaction roles. I have this printing format issue where it is alternating reactions between two embeds. Basically, I want to print 3 reactions first (!claim roles1) with the 3 specific reactions. Then, when I do !claim roles2, it should print out another MessageEmbed with three specific emojis. What is happening is that it is alternating the total emojis on both.

Here is my code below:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const listen = message.content; 
    if(message.author.bot) {
        if(message.embeds) {
            const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'Choose your favorite team!');
            const embedMsg_ = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title === 'Choose your favorite team!');
            if(embedMsg) {
                message.react('797575748307255316')
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('797575748159406112'))
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('797575748181164033'))
                .catch(err => console.error)
            }
            if(embedMsg_) {
                message.react('797575749292916777')
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('797575749171019836'))
                .then(reaction => reaction.message.react('797575749355700234'))
                .catch(err => console.error)
            }

        }
        return; 
    }

    if(listen.toLowerCase() === '!claim roles1') {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Choose your favorite team!")
            .setColor("BLUE")
            .setDescription("<:76ers:797575748307255316> - Philadeplhia 76ers\n" +
            "<:bucks:797575748159406112> - Milwaukee Bucks\n" + 
            "<:bulls:797575748181164033> - Chicago Bulls\n"); 
            
            
    message.channel.send(embed)

        return; 
    }
    if(listen.toLowerCase() === '!claim roles2') {
        const messageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Choose your favorite team!")
        .setColor("BLUE")
        .setDescription("<:raptors:797575749292916777> - Toronto Raptors\n" +
        "<:rockets:797575749171019836> - Houston Rockets\n" +
        "<:spurs:797575749355700234> - San Antonio Spurs\n");
        message.channel.send(messageEmbed)
    
            return; 
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the issue is by the question you asked but you say you're expecting it to output 3 emojis when `!claim roles1` is used and a different set of 3 emojis when `!claim roles2` is used but `embedMsg` and `embedMsg_` are always going to result to true meaning all 6 emojis will always display. Both of those checks are checking for the same title which both embeds have so all 6 emojis display each time. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried to make the two strings different (I put an extra space for embedMsg_) but it displayed the same emojis used for !claim roles1 in !claim roles2.

Comment: I just tried this changing the second to "Choose your favorite sports team!" and it displayed a different set of emojis for each set. The only thing I'm doing different than in your example is using different emojis, I just copy pasted some emojis from the docs.